# How to create a section whose title looks different in the table of content?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyphenation

I'm writing my thesis, and one of the sections has a title which looks good in the table of content, but it's too long in the main text, so that it goes on the new line by hyphenating one of the words. More in specific, it looks like this:

In the toc:

2.1 Conservative Extensions and Inseparability Relations

In the main text:

2.1 Conservative Extensions and Inseparability Re-

lations

I would like still to have 1 line in the toc, but to decide where to go on the new line in the main text. Do you have any suggestion? I don't even know how to google for this problem...

Comment: `\section[toc title]{main \\ title}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- if that section title is run-in and should be justified with the rest of the text, you don't want that space before ` \\ `.

Comment: @klaraspina -- if the section title isn't run in, you could `\mbox` the last word.  better still would be to disallow hyphenation entirely in section titles and set them ragged right, but how that's done depends on what document class you're using, and you don't say.

Comment: @David: your advice works fine, thank you very much!

Comment: @barbara: I'm using the class 'thesis' provided by my university

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way is to use

```
 \section[toc title]{main\\ title}
```